# Default value not reflecting-shared preferences

Tags: android, checkbox, default, sharedpreferences

I have a settings class that extends PreferenceActivity. I have a checkbox preference in the corresponding preferences.xml. The default value is false. But, I set it to true during a run and whenever the application launches, the value is set to true. I need it to take the default value which is false each time the application launches. Shouldn't that be the default behaviour?

Comment: If you hard uninstall the app, then reinstall it, is it false? If so, this is the expected behavior. Changing a preference should save its value for later launches; the default will only be used if not previously set.

Comment: yes, I uninstalled it and tried. It's false. Oh I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As per comments on the OP*:

`PreferencesActivity` saves each item in the preferences for use later in the app. These values are also retained after exit. A "default" value only shows up if the preference has not been set before, which means your value will only be `false` until someone sets it to `true`. They can later change it back to `false`, but it will never again use the default value.

To reset to the default value, the application must be uninstalled and reinstalled (or have its data cleared via Application Manager).

Comment: I have a Preference in my PreferenceActivity. On click of this Preference I start a ListActivty for result. Will this selected ListItem(and what value will it take? The display text?) be written into the SharedPreferences automatically?

Comment: When you set the `Preference`, you used the XML and gave it an `android:key` value, did you not? That should be the key it is saved under. And yes, it should be saved automatically.

Comment: That's what I thought but in onCreate when I try to access that value like: mCurrentTrack = mSharedPreferences.getString("MusicTrack", null); I always get a null in mCurrentTrack. Why do you think that is? The value doesn't seem to persist.

Comment: Without seeing the XML and other preference details, it's impossible to say. Can you open a new question with the preference XML, preference code, and the specifics of your `ListActivity`?

Comment: Ok. Please check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257151/preference-value-not-in-sharedpreferences-android